# How to let JTable know that it should display new data if new data file was selected

Tags: java, swing, events, jtable

I have a menu item that opens a file chooser dialog. In that dialog a file should be selected and opened. If file is valid the data from it should be added to a table on the content pane of main frame. I was able to implement everything but getting a data file from OpenFile to MainWindow after checking it. 
Code example:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    MainWindow() {
        //setting frame size, visibility, etc.
        JMenu m = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem mi = new JMenuItem("Open");
        mi.addActionListener(new OpenFile());
        m.add(mi);
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.add(m);
        setJMenuBar(mb);
        JTable table = new JTable();
    }
}

class OpenFile implements ActionListener {
    File file;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //opening file chooser dialog, getting file, checking that file is valid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TableModel` is responsible for providing notification back to the table when it's content or structure has changed, allowing the table the opportunity to decide how best to update itself to meet the requirements of the change

Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Firing data change events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire) in particular...

**Updated**

In order to be able to manipulate the `TableModel`, you need a reference to it.  The final solution will depend on how you've implemented the table model, but the basic concept is the same.

```
public class OpenFile implements ActionListener {

    private YourTableModel model;

    public OpenFile (YourTableModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
        model.updateModelWithContent(...); // Or what ever method you provide
    }
```

The model you pass to this class should be the same model you supply to the table.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i asked how to get the file reference to MainWindow from OpenFile class right after mi fires ActionEvent. Maybe it's not clear from the question that table have no data to show.

Comment: You need a reference of the `TableModel` with which you can populate the content from the file with...

Comment: How to implement this? Pass this reference through a constructor of OpenFile class?  I'm not really so interesting with populating a table. All I need is a general idea how to get a ref, in this case a file ref from OpenFile, from some listener to a completely different location, in this case to MainWindow class. Is it possible to do? Or  is there another way how to do so?